# What is the possible random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Here is a probability problem from Ross.

**Suppose that a bus starts from point A and reaches point B, covering a total of 100 miles between A and B. Suppose also that it suffers a breakdown on its way, the breakdown point being uniformly distributed over the distance between A and B. Two models for setting up helpstations are suggested:**

1. helpstations at distances of $0,50,100$ miles from A;
2. helpstations at distances of $25,50,75$ miles from A.

**Determine which one is the more convenient model.**

Of course, the distance of breakdown point from A is a random variable, trivially. But what exactly is the question *asking*? Please give me only a hint of the required random variable, nothing more.

Please treat this as a homework problem and just give the hint only. Not even a working hint: just what can be the possible random variable here.

I have contemplated $X=$distance between breakdown point and nearest helpstation. But I am not really understanding what the question is demanding.

Comment: Let $X$ be the location of the breakdown and $Y$ the distance to the nearest help station. The value of $Y$ depends on $X$ as well as which of the two choices of help station locations is in use. Thus, one possible definition of "more convenient model" is the model for which $E[Y]$ is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you need to calculate the average cost due to any possible break down. If $X$ is uniform, it means your breakdown point can be at any point on the way with same probability. Given this your cost is to reach to the shortest help center and the amount of distance that you require to reach to the help center is your cost for, say, one realization. Since you have equally probable possiblities, you only need to average all such (uncountably many) costs. For example consider scheme 1. and you are at 25km then your cost is exactly 25. Can you generalize it?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Shortly I will try the problem as guided by you.